# Using .sub() over a variable length dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a need to calculate the difference between one static column in a dataframe and some variable amount of columns that make up the rest of the dataframe.

My data look like this:

```
School District | 01-01-2017 | 01-02-2017 |...| 02-01-2017 | BaseData |
District A      |     1      |      5     |...|      3     |     1    |
District B      |     2      |      4     |...|      3     |     2    |
District C      |     3      |      3     |...|      3     |     3    |
District D      |     4      |      2     |...|      3     |     4    |
```

I want to subtract "BaseData" from every other column headed with a date such that the final table will look like this:

```
School District | 01-01-2017 | 01-02-2017 |...| 02-01-2017 | BaseData |
District A      |     0      |     -4     |...|     -2     |     0    |
District B      |     0      |     -2     |...|     -1     |     0    |
District C      |     0      |      0     |...|      0     |     0    |
District D      |     0      |      2     |...|      1     |     0    |
```

The amount of columns between "school district" and "base data" is variable.  I tried using `finaltable = basetable[[1:-1]].sub(basetable['BaseData'], axis=0)` but it appears that the `[1:-1]` does not work (raises syntax error).  I know I can return any number of pre-selected columns using `[1, 2, 3, etc.]`, but the dates in the table are dynamic and there could be any number of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by position:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sub(df['BaseData'], axis=0)
print (df)
  School District  01-01-2017  01-02-2017  02-01-2017  BaseData
0      District A           0           4           2         0
1      District B           0           2           1         0
2      District C           0           0           0         0
3      District D           0          -2          -1         0
```

Or:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:-1] = df.iloc[:, 1:-1].sub(df['BaseData'], axis=0)
print (df)
  School District  01-01-2017  01-02-2017  02-01-2017  BaseData
0      District A           0           4           2         1
1      District B           0           2           1         2
2      District C           0           0           0         3
3      District D           0          -2          -1         4
```

Comment: Thank you, jezrael.  I deleted the question because I found an answer, but  I undeleted it because you said it was a good question.  Perhaps someone else can learn from it.

Comment: Your question is nice, because have sample data, desired output and what you try. Naybe for you it is no problem, but many question miss something with it...

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer through a somewhat unrelated question shortly after posting:

Using the .columns() modifier:

`finaltable = basetable[basetable.columns[1:]].sub(basetable['BaseData'], axis=0)`